# Is this the right approach to TDD?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, tdd

New to TDD here. Just need some guidance on if I'm approaching this the right way. I'm looking to convert Roman numeral string to integer using TDD. I have 2 concerns (also, if anyone can point out other concerns, please do):

- It feels like I may be writing too many similar tests like
  I_returns_1, II_returns_2 etc.. Should I be combining some of these
  tests? Or to count to 20, should I really have 20 tests?
- Also have I refactored enough? Otherwise, any suggestions?

  ```
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Specials = new Dictionary<string, int>()
  {
      {"IV", 4},
      {"IX", 9}
  };

  public static int? Convert(string input)
  {
      if (input == null) return null;

      var processed = input;
      var counter = 0;

      foreach (var special in Specials)
      {
          if (!processed.Contains(special.Key)) continue;

          processed = processed.Replace(special.Key, "");
          counter = counter + special.Value;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < processed.Length; i++)
      {
          if (processed[i] == 'X')
              counter = counter + 10;
          if (processed[i] == 'V')
              counter = counter + 5;
          if (processed[i] == 'I')
              counter++;
      }

      return counter;
  }
  ```

And here are the tests which created above...

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Check_Null_returns_Exception()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert(null);

        Assert.AreEqual(result,null);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void I_returns_1()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("I");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 1);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void II_returns_2()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("II");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 2);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Multiple_I_returns_number()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("III");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 3);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IV_returns_4()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("IV");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 4);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void V_returns_5()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("V");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 5);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void VI_returns_6()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("VI");

        Assert.AreEqual(result, 6);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void VII_returns_7()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("VII");

        Assert.AreEqual(7,result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void VIII_returns_8()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("VIII");

        Assert.AreEqual(8,result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IX_returns_9()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("IX");

        Assert.AreEqual(9, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void X_returns_10()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("X");

        Assert.AreEqual(10, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_XI_to_XIII()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(11, Program.Convert("XI"));
        Assert.AreEqual(12, Program.Convert("XII"));
        Assert.AreEqual(13, Program.Convert("XIII"));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void XIV_returns_14()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XIV");

        Assert.AreEqual(14, result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void XV_returns_15()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XV");

        Assert.AreEqual(15, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void XVI_returns_16()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XVI");

        Assert.AreEqual(16, result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void XVI_returns_17()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XVII");

        Assert.AreEqual(17, result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void XVI_returns_18()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XVIII");

        Assert.AreEqual(18, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void XIX_returns_19()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XIX");

        Assert.AreEqual(19, result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void XX_returns_20()
    {
        var result = Program.Convert("XX");

        Assert.AreEqual(20, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the unit test names should be meaningful and not just describe the code.

`II_returns_2` doesn't explain what the test tries to guarantee. `II_should_be_interpreted_as_the_roman_representation_of_2` better explains the ***business rule***.

That's important, because when you come back to the code a year from know an read the test name `II_returns_2` you would have no freaking clue to why you wrote that test. (well, in this trivial example you probably would, but not in a typical application)

The next thing is that the method names will be similar, but as the code path is different (the application executes different branches depending on the roman number) you need to have different tests.

Luckily for you, a couple of different unit test libraries support using attributes to define a set of different test values.

Here is an sample from [xunit](https://xunit.github.io/).

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("I", 1)]
[InlineData("II", "2")]
[InlineData("III", "3")]
public void test(string roman, int number)
{
    var actual = Program.Convert(roman);

    Assert.AreEqual(actual, number);

}
```

Comment: How about the algorithm? Do you think there's room for improvement?

Comment: @DrZeuso: That's a question for the CodeReview site. But I would move the `Special` block to a separate non-public method and then use a `switch` statement instead of `if` statement for the other check.

Answer (score 1):

Repetition is never good ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) so similar tests shall be represented with a single test. I am not familiar with Microsoft's Unit Tests framework but in NUnit, you can use [TestCase](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/TestCase-Attribute) attribute and write something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class RomanNumeralConverter_Tests
{
   [TestCase("I", 1)]
   [TestCase("II", 2)]
   [TestCase("III", 3)]
   [TestCase("IV", 4)]
   [TestCase("V", 5)]
   [TestCase("VI", 6)]
   // etc...
   public void Convert_returns_decimal_representation(string roman, int expectedDecimal)
   {
      var result = Program.Convert(roman);
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedDecimal, result);
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's some repetition in the algorithm as well. Do you think there's room for improvement?